# How to use Service Account to access GMAIL API for a GSuite email account

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-client, google-api-nodejs-client

I want my service account to impersonate one of the users in the GSuite.
I have

- created a project via GCP
- enabled GMail API in the project
- added a service account to that project
- enabled the `domain-wide delegation` in the service account settings on the `GCP`
- added an `API Client` with `service account id` in advanced settings via Google Admin panel for the `GSuite`

While going through docs (java), I saw this

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .createDelegated("user@example.com");
```

Here they are specifying which user the service account should impersonate. This code is in java. I need to accomplish the same thing in nodejs.

While going through documentation of `nodejs-client` for `googleapis`, I found this:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: '/path/to/your-secret-key.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
});
```

and

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

// set auth as a global default
google.options({
  auth: oauth2Client
});
```

**What is the difference between `GoogleAuth` and `OAuth2` here?**

**How do I set everything up so that my node.js application can access `user@abc.xyz` mail via the service account?**

**How do I specify the `email` I want to access via `service account`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#application-default-credentials) specifies:

> Rather than manually creating an OAuth2 client, JWT client, or Compute
> client, the auth library can create the correct credential type for
> you, depending upon the environment your code is running under.

In other words:

- `google.auth.GoogleAuth` is a library tool that creates dynamically the correct credentials for you if you do not know which credentials you need
- `google.auth.OAuth2` always creates specifically OAuth2 credentials
- For most applications where you authenticate as yourself OAth2 is what you need
- However for using a service account you need to create a `JSON Web Token` a specified [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens)

- Double-check that you created [service account crendetials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys), preferably as a `json` file, enabled [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and provided the service account with the necessary [scopes](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en) in the admin console.
- To implement impersonation into your code, add the line `subject: USER_EMAIL` when creating the JWT client.

**Sample**

```js
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
//THE PATH TO YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT CRENDETIALS JSON FILE
const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');

async function main() {
  const client = new JWT({
    email: keys.client_email,
    key: keys.private_key,
    scopes: ['YOUR SCOPES HERE'],
    subject: USER_EMAIL
  });
  const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you, ziganotschka!